# Open a pdf file from local directory on button Click in QML

Tags: qt, qml

```
    Image {
    id: user_guide_over
    source: "qrc:/images/loginPage/user_guide_over.png"
    x: ((parent.width/rootItemWidth)*1004)
    y: ((parent.height/rootItemHeight)*646)
    opacity: 1
    visible: false
    width: ((bgRect.width/rootItemWidth)*sourceSize.width)
    height: ((bg.height/rootItemHeight)*sourceSize.height) }
```

The above is a image *button* that I have created. Now I have my PDF file inside my *images* folder and what to open it in read mode. I tried the following approach. When the above button is clicked, I get a pop up "*You'll need a new app to open this qrc link*". What is the Alternative approach to this, to open the pdf file in default pdf reader in any system.

```
     MouseArea {
         anchors.fill: user_guide
         onClicked: {
          Qt.openUrlExternally("qrc:images/ug.pdf");

            }
```

Comment: I did a quick test and it didn't work for me when I used a resource in the .qrc file. But if I specified the path like this: "file:/path/to/some/file.pdf" then it worked just fine. Does that work for you?

Comment: no sir , that doesn't work well for me : )

Comment: Can you clarify why that doesn't work? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing the / in openUrlExternally link.

It's worth using js function or C++ to verify the file actually exists so this works as you intend